# Can't create blob container on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

The following code throws an error on the "CreateIfNotExist" method call. I am attempting to connect to my Azure Blob storage and create a new container called "images"

```
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
    new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("my_account_name", "my shared key"),
    "https://blob.core.windows.net/",
    "https://queue.core.windows.net/",
    "https://table.core.windows.net/"
);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();
```

The error is:

```
[StorageClientException: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.]
```

The "images" container does not exist but I was expecting it to be created instead of an error to be thrown. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried HTTP instead of HTTPS but the result is the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out that I must use a different syntax

```
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
   new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("my_account_name", "my shared key"));
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); 
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images"); 
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Notice how the end points are omited. Evidently, the CloudBlobClient can figure out the appropriate URIs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the account name and shared key are correct?  You might try installing Fiddler to take a look at the HTTP traffic to make sure nothing there looks suspicious.